# Deploying a Web service (WAR) application in Weblogic 11g with WS- Security enabled - Error

Tags: web-services, web, weblogic11g

I am trying to deploy our proprietary web service application (WAR) into Weblogic  11g server. I have created the WAR using Eclipse Indigo and Java 1.6.

I got the below error,

> Messages  An error occurred during activation of changes, please see
>   the log for details.  Error encountered during prepare phase of
>   deploying WebService module 'TWSWebSec.war'. When processing
>   WebService module 'TWSWebSec.war'. Can't find wsdl
>   /wsdls/wsc10/wscoor.wsdl  When processing WebService module
>   'TWSWebSec.war'. Can't find wsdl /wsdls/wsc10/wscoor.wsdl

The deployment has been successfully installed.

I tried with a hack of creating wscoor.wsdl into the specified folder and created a new WAR, this time the error was that it is a premature closure of file, which meant the file is identified and there is nothing in the file to read.

After this, i tried to input manually the service, interfaces, operation as per the created Service endpoint interfaces/ Web services, this time i got the error

> An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log
>   for details.  Error encountered during prepare phase of deploying
>   WebService module 'TWSWebSec.war'. When processing WebService module
>   'TWSWebSec.war'. Can't find wsdl
>   /wsdls/wsc11/wstx-wscoor-1.1-wsdl-200702.wsdl  When processing
>   WebService module 'TWSWebSec.war'. Can't find wsdl
>   /wsdls/wsc11/wstx-wscoor-1.1-wsdl-200702.wsdl   The deployment has
>   been successfully installed.

Am I missing anything here? Is it a configuration problem? Do I need to update any JARs I use?

Please help. Also let me know if more information required?

Answer (score 0):

I post this because there is a chance that you may be in a case that is similar to what I experienced. I had the same error (i.e. "can't find wsdl") yesterday afternoon when trying to make WebLogic deploy a client created with Eclipse's web service generator using CXF. It just never worked. Today I replaced that client with one made one using WebLogic's generator, also in Eclipse, where it is found under Oracle, WebLogic, Web and Service Client. That worked for me. It seems that WebLogic uses Metro and not CXF. There is certainly nothing wrong with CXF but it does not seem to make a good pair with WebLogic.
Best regards Johannes